# How to write same level slug pages under page in Nuxt js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I want to route pages depend on incoming url. I have 2 different pages which works like a slug. I need to create my url like in samples. Is there any way to check url params and route them to right slug page inside extendRoutes or somewhere else which will not affect page load speed ?

```
page
 --_category
 --subcategory

sample url

http://192.168.52.215:3000/news. :category slug
http://192.168.52.215:3000/local-news.   :subcategory slug
```

```
extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      {
        name: 'category',
        path: '/:category',
        component: resolve('pages/_category.vue'),
      },

      {
        name: 'category',
        path: '/:subcategory',
        component: resolve('pages/subcategory.vue'),
      },
    );
```

For example , if my paramater includes news, it should go _category slug otherwise it should go to subcategory slug

Answer (score 0):

you can change name for routes like this

```js
extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
  {
    name: 'category',
    path: '/:category',
    component: resolve('pages/_category.vue'),
  },
  {
    name: 'subcategory',
    path: '/:subcategory',
    component: resolve('pages/subcategory.vue'),
  }
);
```

And when you try to navigate do this :

```js
// Navigate to Category Slug
this.$router.push({ name: 'category': params: { category: 'news' } });

// Navigate to Subcategory Slug
this.$router.push({ name: 'subcategory': params: { subcategory: 'local-news' } });
```